# How does OpenCL host execute kernels on itself?

Tags: opencl

When we have multi-core CPU, OpenCL treats it as a single device with multiple compute units and for every device we can create some command queues.How can CPU as a host, create a command queue on itself? I think in this situation it become multithreading rather than parallel computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices, including most CPU devices can be segmented into sub-devices using the extension ["cl_ext_device_fission"](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/ext/cl_ext_device_fission.txt). When you use device fission, you are still getting parallel processing in that the host thread can do other tasks while the kernel is running on some CPU cores.

When not using device fission, the CPU device will block essentially block the host program while a kernel is running. Even if some opencl implementations are non-blocking during kernel execution, the performance hit to the host would be too great to allow much work to be done by the host thread.

So it's still parallel computation, but I guess the host application's core is technically multi-threading during kernel execution.

Answer (score 0):

It's parallel computing using multithreading. When you use an OpenCL CPU driver and enqueue kernels for the CPU device, the driver uses threads to execute the kernel, in order to fully leverage all of the CPUs cores (and also typically uses vector instructions like SSE to fully utilize each core).